# Mistake with the function add () cakephp 1.3.8

Tags: cakephp, controller

Here is the controller of my model Taxon
public function add() {

```
 if ($this->Session->check('Auth.PaUser') === true) {
         $view_mode = false;
         //$this->set('title_for_layout', 'Ajout du taxon');//   $this->set('title_for_layout', $this->name . ' > Ajout');
         //$this->set('submit_url', 'add');
         $this->set('view_mode', $view_mode);

     if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Taxon->create();
        if ($this->Taxon->save($this->data)){
            //$this->set('mess_type', 'active');
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Le taxon a été enregistré', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->Taxon->id));
        }
     } else {
           $this->set('mess_type', 'error');
           $this->Session->setFlash('Erreur(s) lors de l\'ajout');
           $this->set('invalidFields', $this->Taxon->invalidFields());
        }

    $refbiblios = $this->Taxon->Refbiblio->find('list', array('fields' => array('Refbiblio.nom_ref')));
    $synonyme = $this->Taxon->find('list', array('fields' => array('Taxon.nom_taxon')));
    $this->set('refbiblios', $refbiblios);
    $this->set('synonyme', $synonyme);
 }
}
```

a taxon hasandbelongtomany Refbiblio (Bibliographic reference) and belong to Taxon (for synonym)
but when i click on save in the view, i have that message
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\gecol\gecol\app_model.php on line 43
please help me 
for a long time I tried to solve this mistake but without success

Comment: can you paste the code from `Refbiblio` model?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a mistake in your models and associations. However you can solve this problem by using **loadModel** before calling find on Refbiblio model. This will solve your problem but you have to try **not** to load models manually. Try to correct your model associations

```
$this->loadModel('Refbiblio');
$refbiblios = $this->Refbiblio->find('list', array('fields' => array('Refbiblio.nom_ref')));
```